# How to Handle Login and Registration by Username?

Tags: web2py

I tried to change the default login style to username based login. For that, in the db.py, I wrote:

```
from gluon.tools import Auth, Crud, Service, PluginManager, prettydate
auth = Auth(db)
crud, service, plugins = Crud(db), Service(), PluginManager()
auth.define_tables(username=True, signature=False, migrate=False)
auth_table=auth.settings.table_user
auth_table.username.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, auth_table.username)
```

When I am trying to register for a new user, it gives me this error:

```
<class 'sqlite3.OperationalError'> no such column: auth_user.username
```

I would like to know how to handle this correctly. Also, it would be really helpful to have a good explanation on how exposing and addressing these tables is working. I am very new to this and finding it really confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initially created the Auth tables without the username, then there will be no "username" field in the auth_user table. Because you have `auth.define_tables(..., migrate=False)`, the DAL will not run the migration to add the new field. So, try temporarily changing migrate to True so the field will be added.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it! I had the wrong idea about migrate, seems like. I thought it is set to false if I want to re-use the same database tables for different applications. I did not understand how that should affect changing the primary key from e-mail address to username.